# Date conversion in SQL Server throws error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to  convert a date in `mm/dd/yyyy` format

```
select convert(date,'31/12/2013',101)
```

but I'm getting this error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

How to do this? My system (Windows 7) has a `dd-mm-yyyy` format.. will system date format will have any impact on it?`

Answer (score 2):

see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

101 is the US style (mm/dd/yyyy)

try 103 (dd/mm/yyyy) which is British/French

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '31/12/2013', 103)
```

Answer (score 2):

Style `101` is the **US** style, so this has months first - your string represents the 12th day of the 31st month ....

What you need to use is style **103** (British/French) which uses the day first - so this string is 31st of December:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '31/12/2013', 103)
```

See [the official MSDN SQL Server Books Online Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) on `CAST` and `CONVERT` and what styles are defined and what they mean